# Simple Apps Script timing out on execution

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am only beginner level at C+ and I'm trying to execute what I think is a simple script in Apps Script for this spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lu0_B1OdjU6Y5KF4zomCpQNiGCGklVoZDF8rQ8HQBhQ/edit?usp=sharing
The execution is timing out and it doesn't give me much information as to why but it has to be something to do with the parts of the template I have changed. Namely just the for loop in task 3. Maybe the way i have concatenated too? I am not familiar with Java and may be missing something very obvious. I'm not familiar with how it should be set out either so please be kind.

```
function routineActivator() {
  /** 
  Task 1) Open the Event  Calendar.
  **/
  
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var calendarId = 'myEmail';
  var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
  
 /** 
  Task 2) Pull each shift information into the code, in a form that the code can understand.
 **/
 
  var routine = spreadsheet.getRange('A4:D74').getValues();
  

  /**
  Task 3) Do the work!
 **/
  
  for (x=0; x<routine.length; x++) {
       
       
       var task = routine[x];
       var des = task[3]
       if(des=1){
         var label = task[2];
         var startTime = task[0] + task[1];
         while (des != 2){
           var endTime = task[0] + task[1];
           task++;
          }
         eventCal.createEvent(label, startTime, endTime);
        }       
      }
     
       
       /**
       Task 4) Make it easy to use.
       **/
       
       function onOpen() {
          var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
          ui.createMenu('Sync to Calendar')
               .addItem('Schedule tasks now', 'routineActivator')
       }
}
```

I have tried to run it but it loops and times out.

Comment: `if(des=1)` will not check for value. A single "=" sets value.`if(des==1)` is what you need.

And you may want to mask your email address. :-)

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). It is difficult to answer your question because it is unclear what you are trying to do. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the following will loop forever and never exit:

```
  if (des = 1) {
    while (des != 2) {
    }
  }
```

`des` will always be `1` because you are using the *assignment* operator `=` instead of the *comparison* operator `===`.

Changing the operator is not enough to fix the problem, though, because when `des` is `1`, it is not `2`, and the `while` loop will never exit. You need to modify `des` in the `while` loop.

Comment: To your second point, I was trying to get it to read the next row of data by using 
task++;  then it would assign a new value to des until it found a 2 and exit the while loop. then assigning the new task[1] value as endTime.
It appears to still be stuck in the loop as you said it would. Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: This is the updated code:

for (x=0; x<routine.length; x++) {
       
       
       var task = routine[x];
       var des = task[3]
       if(des === 1){
         var label = task[2];
         var startTime = task[0] + task[1];
         while (des != 2){
           task++;
          }
         var endTime = task[0] + task[1];
         eventCal.createEvent(label, startTime, endTime);
        }       
      }

Comment: Does task++; change the variable "des" outside of the while loop?

Comment: _Does task++; change the variable "des"_ — no it does not. Each variable that contains a primitive such as a number of text string is separate from other variables. Use something like `routine[x + y]` where `y` starts at `1`. See [Apps Script at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) and [Clean Code JavaScript](https://github.com/ryanmcdermott/clean-code-javascript). Please ask only [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741).